# Devforce's MakeWeak eventhandler extension create memory leak?

Tags: devforce

(I am using DF 7.2.3 with Silverlight)

Using the ideablade devforce's MakeWeak extension on events to handle them as weakreference, I thought it would prevent memory leak. But I noticed all the objects using MakeWeak are never released.

In a simple test on a Viewmodel, if I register an event with MakeWeak then GC never release the viewmodel.
if I replace the code with a standard += eventmethod and -= eventmethode, the GC releases the viewmodel.

Here is how I use the MakeWeak :

```
entityManagerProvider.ManagerCreated += 
      new EventHandler<EntityManagerCreatedEventArgs>(EntityManagerCreated)
                       .MakeWeak(eh => entityManagerProvider.ManagerCreated -= eh);
```

with the method **EntityManagerCreated** as **internal**.

Is this a bug or do I use it the wrong way ?

Comment: Your usage looks correct.  I assume you've already got an InternalsVisibleTo attribute in your assembly to give IdeaBlade.Core.SL access to your internal members.  If the EntityManagerCreated handler is defined in your view model class, then objects of that class should be garbage collected when they go out of scope.  If you're seeing otherwise, can you provide a small repro sample showing this?

Comment: Yes I have InternalsVisibleTo set for Ideablade.Core.SL. If you try the Cocktail application will notice the problem (note : you need to click on edit while browsing the data to create a dedicated UOW. Here is what JustTrace give me after that : http://postimg.org/image/arc7qf33n/

Comment: I made a mistake in my previous comment. I meant the problem exist in Temphire and not in cocktail itself.

Comment: Any news on this issue Kim ?

Comment: I asked the Cocktail developer to take a look at this.

Comment: Any input on this Kim ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about the delay. I looked into this in the context of Cocktail and I couldn't reproduce this. I didn't look specifically at TempHire as there might be a memory leak in TempHire, but instead I put together a very small sample that demonstrates that there doesn't appear to be a memory leak with weak event handlers in DevForce. You can download the sample from my OneDrive. You should see three buttons. If you click the Create VM button it creates a new instance of a child VM that subscribes to the above event in the EntityManagerProvider and the app maintains a count of child VM instances. The last created instance is made the active item in the shell. You can create as many child VMs as you like and see the counter increment. The shell releases the previous child VM whenever you create a new one. Click the Close VM button to close the current active VM. Then click the GC button to trigger a garbage collection and you should see the counter go back to zero or one if you still have one VM active in the shell. If you then go to the ChildViewModel constructor and change the weak event handler to a .NET event handler and repeat the exercise, you will see that the counter never goes to zero, because the EntityManagerProvider keeps a reference to every view model that you create.

http://1drv.ms/1tb6tXH

Comment: hi marcel, thanks for your test project which is proving the pb isn't related to the WeakReference itself. It looks like the problem is inside cocktail when you query datas (use of UOW, GlobalCache and Repository).
I updated the SL version of Tempire, I added into the search module the GC button and it's counter. When  StaffingResourceDetailViewModel.LoadDataAsync is called the GC never release the VM. Comment the call to LoadDataAsync and the VM will be released. This issue is a huge problem to me as close to nothing get released at all !  http://tinyurl.com/oljk65b

Comment: I ran TempHire through the ANTS Memory Profiler and turns out there were some event handler snafus in some of the child view models. I fixed them and pushed the updated code to Github. There doesn't appear to be an issue in Cocktail or DevForce. The issue was in TempHire itself and as always, TempHire is just a sample and we make no guarantee that it is free of bugs. Use as-is at your own risk. Here's the commit that fixes the issue to see what I've changed. https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Cocktail/commit/b2e634a0f5f275d626a99fe4d33266637612f8eb

Comment: yes I know Temphire is just a sample, I just used it to show the same issue I was on my own application. I already tried to set all the uow, service to null in the deactivate(true). The VM are inded collected by the GC but the uow, repository still remain in the memory and are never freed. Did you see that too in ANTS ?

Comment: Yes, the UoW etc. was kept alive by the buggy VMs as well. After fixing them, things were properly collected. However, I missed a couple of other places where things weren't released and I just fixed those and pushed the updated code to Github. I also discovered a potential issue in Caliburn.Micro in the process that I had to work around. You can see my additional changes in this commit https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Cocktail/commit/c55c19ec530f7f620a88f1413b4ffc1bf180f56b.

Comment: If you run your app through ANTS Memory Profiler or a similar tool that shows you what's holding references to those objects, you should be able to track down the issue in your app. ANTS has a 14 day trial license if you want to give it a shot.